# GLSL shaders not working. No compile errors, and used glUseProgram

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I came up with code to render a rectangle, but the shaders won't work. It still has the blank white color.

Here I will include the important code

Main:

```
float verts[] = {
    -.5f, -.5f, .0f,
    -.5f,  .5f, .0f,
     .5f,  .5f, .0f,
     .5f,  .5f, .0f,
     .5f, -.5f, .0f,
    -.5f, -.5f, .0f
};

Shader shader("basicVert.glsl", "basicFrag.glsl");

GLuint VBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), &verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

shader.enable();
```

Shader.cpp (class functions)

```
Shader::Shader(const string vpath, const string fpath) {
    Shader();
    current_vpath = vpath;
    current_fpath = fpath;
    shaderID = init();
}

Shader::Shader(const char *vpath, const char *fpath) {
    Shader(string(vpath), string(fpath));
}

Shader::~Shader() {
    shaderID = NULL;
    glDeleteProgram(shaderID);
}

void Shader::enable() {
    glUseProgram(shaderID);
}

GLuint Shader::makeVertextShader(const char* source) {
    GLuint vertShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertShaderID, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertShaderID);
    GLint r;
    glGetShaderiv(vertShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &r);
    if (r == GL_FALSE) {
        GLint l;
        glGetShaderiv(vertShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &l);
        cout << l << endl;
        char *bfer = new char[l];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertShaderID, l, &l, bfer);
        cerr << "Failed to compile VERTEXT SHADER! FILE NAME: " << 
        current_vpath << endl;
        cerr << bfer << endl;
        glDeleteShader(vertShaderID);
        delete[] bfer;
        return NULL;
    }
    return vertShaderID;
}

GLuint Shader::makeFragmentShader(const char* source) {
  GLuint fragShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(fragShaderID, 1, &source, NULL);
  glCompileShader(fragShaderID);
  GLint r;
  glGetShaderiv(fragShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &r);
  if (r == GL_FALSE) {
      GLint l;
      glGetShaderiv(fragShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &l);
      char *bfer = new char[l];
      glGetShaderInfoLog(fragShaderID, l, &l, bfer);
      cerr << "Failed to compile FRAGMENT SHADER! FILE NAME: " << 
              current_fpath << endl;
      cerr << bfer << endl;
      glDeleteShader(fragShaderID);
      delete[] bfer;
      return NULL;
  }
  return fragShaderID;
}

GLuint Shader::init() {
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    const string vs = readFile(current_vpath);
    const string vf = readFile(current_fpath);

    const char *vertexsrc = vs.c_str();
    const char *fragmentsrc = vf.c_str();

    GLuint vertShaderID = this->makeVertextShader(vertexsrc);
    GLuint fragShaderID = this->makeFragmentShader(fragmentsrc);

    glAttachShader(program, vertShaderID);
    glAttachShader(program, fragShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);
    glDeleteShader(vertShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(fragShaderID);
    return program;
}
```

GLSL Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main(){

    gl_Position = position;

}
```

GLSL Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main(){

    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = color;

}
```

Comment: Are you calling `glDrawArrays` somewhere? Also without seeing your shaders it's hard to know if the problem is there

Comment: both of your shaders shouldn't compile. Did you actually check the output of your program? Also, your code is lacking checks for link failures.

Comment: It compiles, and it does output errors if their are any.

Comment: There is no  gl_FragColor in GLSL 300

Comment: unless it happens in your make*shader methods, where are you checking the result of shader compilation? Checking the shader compile and link logs would have helped you find this error

Comment: @Rabbid76 None of these have worked for me yet :(

Comment: @Rabbid76 I use `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` and `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Issue has still not been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

`gl_FragColor` is no longer supported in modern versions of GLSL

so it will be in Vertex Shader,

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = position;
}
```

in FS,

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main()
{
color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
//gl_FragColor is no longer supported in modern versions of GLSL  
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks. I didn't know that Layout Qualifier are also used for an output.

Answer (score 1):

The vertex and fragment shader have to look like this:

```c
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( position.xyz, 1.0 );
}
```

```c
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

---

Explanation:

There are 2 issues in your code:

1.) While the vertex attribute `position`, in the [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) has the type `vec3`, the [Built-in Variable (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)) `gl_Position` has the type `vec4`.
Either the type of the vertex attribute has to be changed:

```c
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
```

or the assignment to `gl_Position` has to be adapted:

```c
gl_Position = vec4( position.xyz, 1.0 );
```

2.) In the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) either can be used the [Built-in output Variable (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)#Fragment_shader_outputs) `gl_FragColor`:

```c
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = [...];
}
```

or an explicit output variable has to be declared:

```
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = [...];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to lie in the vertex shader: You pass a vec3 `position` to a vec4 `gl_Position` which effectively sets the w-coordinate to 0. What you need for proper rendering is a homogeneous coordinate of 1 (otherwise the division by w is  a division by 0). Try to change your code to

```
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
```

Comment: i just added that and it didn't work. Thanks for help anyway

Comment: Just as a side-note: You are checking the compile status of your shaders, but not the link status of your program.